# How shall we refer to someone who speaks with a country or ... accent in AmE?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

How do the native speakers refer to a person who speaks with a regional accent:
The words which sound natural to me in this sense are:

> a) - He/she speaks with a **country** accent.
>
> b) - He/she speaks with a **rural** accent.
>
> c) - He/she speaks with a **southern** accent.

For me, they all work properly in this situation in AmE. (I am looking for a fixed term or something in common AmE.)

Meanwhile, please let me know how to intensify the sentence? For instance what comes to mind would be something like:

> - He speaks with a **severe** country accent.

Comment: In BrE (and I imagine AmE), you speak with a **strong** [country] accent.

Comment: I would say "He speaks with a *strong* country accent."

Comment: A **strong** or **thick** accent is how I would phrase it.

Comment: If you were speaking about the accents of Americans, you wouldn't typically say a "country accent" or "rural accent" any more than you'd say a "city accent".  Mostly you'd identify accents by region - a Midwestern accent, a New York accent, a southern accent, a Boston accent.  A rural Minnesotan and a rural Texan sound very, very different, so there isn't a single stereotypical "rural" accent to refer to (although you're right, if you said it, I think most people would infer "southern").

Comment: @PMV yes. You're right. That's it' I've heard it from a close AM friend. Just please make your comment an answer to vote it. Meanwhile, please let me know if what you mentioned is an epidemic rule in the US and all people think so? Also, I agree that "rural" doesn't work, but I doubt if regionally "country accent" works.